# Videoview Play Button Always Show Android

Tags: android, video, android-videoview, android-video-player

how to make the video button always appear when playing videos ?
now the button only appears when we click the video, please help me
this is my code .

**MainActivity.java**

```
 val vidAddress = "http:lalala.com/ikon.mp4"
    val vidUri = Uri.parse(vidAddress)

    val fullScreen = intent.getStringExtra("fullScreenInd")

    if ("y" == fullScreen) {
        window.setFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN, WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN)
        setRequestedOrientation(ActivityInfo.SCREEN_ORIENTATION_LANDSCAPE)
        supportActionBar?.hide()
    }

    myVideo.setVideoURI(vidUri)

    val mediaController = FullScreenVideo(this)
    mediaController.setAnchorView(myVideo)
    myVideo.setMediaController(mediaController)


    myVideo.start()
    mediaController.requestFocus()
```

FullscreenVideo

class FullScreenVideo(context: Context) : MediaController(context) {

```
private var fullScreen: ImageButton? = null
private var isFullScreen: String? = null

override fun setAnchorView(view: View) {

    super.setAnchorView(view)

    //image button for full screen to be added to media controller
    fullScreen = ImageButton(super.getContext())

    val params = FrameLayout.LayoutParams(FrameLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, FrameLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT)
    params.gravity = Gravity.RIGHT
    params.rightMargin = 80
    addView(fullScreen, params)

    //fullscreen indicator from intent
    isFullScreen = (context as Activity).intent.getStringExtra("fullScreenInd")

    if ("y" == isFullScreen) {
        fullScreen!!.setImageResource(R.drawable.ic_minimize)
    } else {
        fullScreen!!.setImageResource(R.drawable.ic_fullscreen)
    }

    //add listener to image button to handle full screen and exit full screen events
    fullScreen!!.setOnClickListener {
        val intent = Intent(context, MainActivity::class.java)
        if ("y" == isFullScreen) {
            intent.putExtra("fullScreenInd", "")
        } else {
            intent.putExtra("fullScreenInd", "y")
        }
        (context as Activity).startActivity(intent)
    }
}
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Instead of using the Videoview Play button, you can design your own play button.

```
    <LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
  xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
  android:id="@+id/LinearLayout1"
  android:layout_width="fill_parent"
  android:layout_height="fill_parent"
  android:orientation="vertical">

<FrameLayout
  android:id="@+id/video_frame"
  android:layout_width="fill_parent"
  android:layout_height="480px"
  android:background="#000"
  >

  <VideoView
    android:id="@+id/video_view"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    />

  <ImageButton
    android:id="@+id/play_button"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_gravity="center_vertical|center_horizontal"
    android:src="@drawable/ic_launcher"
    />

</FrameLayout>
```

---

```
mPlayButton = (ImageButton) findViewById(R.id.play_button);
mPlayButton.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        if (mPlayer.isPlaying()) {
            resetPlayer();
        } else {
            playVideo(videoUrl, mVideoView.getHolder());
            // show the media controls
            mController.show();
            // hide button once playback starts
            mPlayButton.setVisibility(View.GONE);
        }
    }
});
```